# Variables overlap when calling thread twice in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm having a problem calling a thread more than once and the variables messing up. I'm new to threads, so I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

```
struct PARAMS
{
    time_t secondsAtStart;
};

DWORD WINAPI ProcessChange(void* parameter) {
    PARAMS* params = (PARAMS*)parameter;
    Sleep(3000);
    _tprintf(TEXT("Seconds: (%d)\n"), params->secondsAtStart);
    return 0;
}


void FileChanged(CString filename, CString action) {
    struct PARAMS *params = NULL;
    params = (struct PARAMS *)malloc(sizeof(PARAMS)+1);
    params->secondsAtStart = time(null);
    // I've also tried it this way.    
    //PARAMS params;
    //params.secondsAtStart = time(NULL);
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ProcessChange, &params, 0, NULL);
    // If I uncomment this, it works, but just one thread runs at a time.
    //WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
}
```

If I don't uncomment the WaitForSingleObject, then the secondsAtStart variable gets corrupted. The end result I need is that if FileChanged gets called 3 times right after one another, I'm going to have the first two runs do nothing and the last one do the action.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: One problem I can see is that you pass `&params` to `ProcessChange`, i.e. the address of what is already a pointer. Clearly, this causes problems as soon as it goes out of scope at the end of `FileChanged`. Just passing `params` is what you should do.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the secondsAtStart variable gets corrupted"?  And am I right in thinking you're trying to update `secondsAtStart` every time `FileChanged` is called, so that `ProcessChange` then checks that enough time has elapsed since the call before performing the action?

Comment: There's a bunch of other, questionable things apart from the mentioned solution. Firstly, why allocate one byte more? Also, why not use new? Then, you could also use unique_ptr/auto_ptr to prevent leaks. Then, just like you don't write `class std::string s = "42";` there is no need for the struct keyword either. Then, put declaration and initialization into the same line and move that to the place that you really need it. Finally, you must `CloseHandle()` the thread handle, otherwise that's a resource leak, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing addresses of (or references to) local variables of a function, i.e. variables of automatic storage, to a thread causes undefined behaviour if the thread lives longer than the function.

In your code, `params` points to an object of dynamic storage, but the pointer itself is a local variable. You pass *its address* `&params` to the thread. This only works if by waiting for the thread to finish you guarantee the pointer lives longer than the thread. Otherwise it causes undefined behaviour, which quite naturally manifests itself in nonsensical values being printed.

Passing `params` instead of `&params` should solve the problem. (Also note that the code as written causes a memory leak; you'll need to make sure you actually `free` the space allocated *after* the thread has finished.)